# How can I implement this program using a dictionary rather than a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I have this program that I have written and I used a list because you can append to it with ease. With a dictionary, you cannot append to it. So I am wondering if there is a way to write this program with a dictionary rather than a list, and if so, how so?

I want the output to stay the same. It's just when you change `store = []` to a dictionary as `store = {}`, then how do I change the rest of the program where I am changing only specific variables to go from list to dictionary?

```
def SSN():

    store = []

    for i in range(0, 100):
        store.append([])
    i = 0
    name = 'key'
    while(name != ''):
        name = input('Enter Name: ')
        if(name == ''):
            if(i<1):
                break
            j=0
            while(j < i):
                print(store[j][0] + ' has SSN ' + store[j][1])
                j = j+1
            break
        j=0
        val = 0
        while(j < i):
            if(name == store[j][0]):
                val = 1
                break
            j = j + 1
        if(val == 1):
            update = input(name + ' has SSN ' + store[j][1] + '. Update? ')
            if(update == 'y'):
                store[j][1] = input('Enter SSN: ')
        else:
            ssn = input('Enter SSN: ')
            store[i].append(name)
            store[i].append(ssn)
            i = i+1
SSN()
```

This runs exactly how I want it but it's just that dictionary I would like.
Thanks!

For output, I have this:

`Enter Name:`john
 `Enter SSN:`1234
 `Enter Name:`mike
 `Enter SSN:`5678
 `Enter Name:`wazowski
 `Enter SSN:`0000
 `Enter Name:`mike
 `mike has SSN 5678. Update?`y
 `Enter SSN:`6644
 `Enter Name:`john
 `john has SSN 1234. Update?`n
 `Enter Name: 
 john has SSN 1234
 mike has SSN 6644
 wazowski has SSN 0000`

Where the spaced out words represent what the user input when prompted by the program.

Comment: Can you please show us an example of input and desired output? It would be easier to understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r updated in the question body. Hopefully this helps a little more. The outcome, I want this to stay the same. It's just when you change `store = []` to a dictionary as `store = {}`, then how do I change the rest of the program where I am changing only specific variables to go from list to dictionary?

Comment: So, would it be correct to say that you want to store (name, ssn) pairs in a dictionary and be able to update the ssn if the name already exists?

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r Correct. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making `store` to a `dict` is a good idea, it would get rid of all the loops you use to find items from it. The changed program would look something like this:

```
def SSN():
    store = {}
    while True:
        name = input('Enter Name: ')
        if not name:
            for k, v in store.items():
                print(k + ' has SSN ' + v)
            break

        if name in store:
            if input(name + ' has SSN ' + store[name] + '. Update? ') != 'y':
                continue

        store[name] = input('Enter SSN: ')
```

In the above [`store.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns key value pairs from the dict where key is name and value is SSN. `name in store` returns boolean value telling if name is in `store` and `store[name] = input('Enter SSN: ')` assigns new value replacing the old one if it existed.

Comment: Great answer. I was working on it myself and I came up with basically the same thing. The main difference was that I used a `try... except KeyError... else` block for the part about updating the SSN, but I like your solution much better (probably the best use of `continue` I've ever seen).

Comment: Just ran this and that is perfect! Thank you so much! I started off with a dictionary and then it was too long and complicated (still learning dictionaries and python) so I went the list route and then here we are!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm looking at this right...
It looks like right now you're creating a list called 'store' and if instead of printing it with your user-friendly layout, you printed just the list, it would look something like

['john', 1234, 'mike', 6644, 'wazowski', 0000]

But instead, you'd rather have a dictionary that looks more like

{'john':1234, 'mike':6644, 'wazowski':0000}

I agree that a dictionary makes way more sense here. Try something like

```
store = {}
name = 'key'
while name != '':
    name = raw_input("Enter Name: ")
    if name == '':
        break
    ssn = raw_input("Enter SSN: ")
    store[name] = ssn
```

The only thing you lose in this case is the ability to see which name was entered first, second, etc. But that doesn't seem as important as being able to easily id which number goes with which name.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to implent lists in dictionaries then try

```
List = [Pie]

Dict = {Apple}

for List in Dict:
print(Dict)
break
```

Maybe that is what your looking for?

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question in the slightest.

Comment: Sorry I'm somewhat inexperienced and I'm just trying to help :(

Comment: oh nvm congrats dude